# Generating DatagridCellinfo out of a custom DatagirdCell for testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datagridview

i have a Problem with `DataGridCell` and `DataGridCellInfo`
The Main Problem is , which the code above dosen't show , that the class `DataGridCellInfo` has a constructor which takes as an param a `DataGridCell` , but if you create a DataGridCell and put it in I always gets an NullreferenceException , whether the Cell is mocked or not .

```
        `mockCell = new Mock<DataGridCell>();
        var tb = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        tb.Text = "test";
        mockCell.Object.Content =tb ;
        var cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(mockCell.Object);
        // do something useful
       `
```

My question is , who does the Constructor work , which attributes am i missing ?
Is it possible to generate such an Info without being the Datagrid ? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: I have checked it , its all by the right name.

Comment: Including the DataGridView tag??